# can not install any extension from magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, php-7

I installed magento 1.9 and used a extension called [Inchoo_PHP7](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7)

but not i cant installed any extension from magento connect, it gives me a error saying that the extension doesnt support my php version.

Comment: Because that extension is for php7 and you may be using php 5.6

Comment: Can u please put extact error on here

Comment: its whgat i just said, it sayis that doesnt support my current php version, it needs to be from php5

Answer (score 1):

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....